# Big-O runtime of String Concatenation explained( Java )?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, string-concatenation

If all the elements of the `words` array are all Strings of fixed length `x`,

```
public String joinWords(String[] words) {
   String sentence = "";
   for (String w : words) {
        sentence = sentence + w; 
   }
   return sentence;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how the runtime of this algorithm becomes `O(xn^2)` ? And how does `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` improve on this ?

Comment: isn't the point of doing homework that you are supposed to figure that our for your self?

Comment: if you research how string concatenation works, then you should be able to figure out the big-o easily.  and there are plenty of examples out there which describe how to use StringBuilder to improve string concat in java.

Comment: @jtahlborn I am actually preparing for an interview and was hoping someone can clarify( don't believe my username, I took Bayesian Statistics a while ago)....

Comment: Although this is certainly a duplicate question, I feel I would be remiss if I neglected to direct anyone to this blog post. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html